# Run JQuery when payment is being processed

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm trying to run a small bit of JQuery when the Place Order button is clicked on my checkout. It'll fade in a div with a spinner in it to show that payment is being processed.

I've tried:

```
$("#place_order").on( "click", function() {
    $(".purchase-processing").fadeIn( "slow" );
    // alert("Place Order Clicked");
});
```

And:

```
$('body').on( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', function(){
    $(".purchase-processing").fadeIn( "slow" );
    // alert("Place Order Clicked");
});
```

Neither of which seem to work- nor does swapping the fadeIn for an alert to test it. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Define "not work". What happens?

Comment: Supplying the relevant HTML will also help

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '#place_order', function() {$(".purchase-processing").fadeIn( "slow" );});`. If that does not work, make sure you are targeting the correct button.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, nothing happens. Div doesn't fade in, and if I comment it out and just have the alert, the alert doesn't happen. With the code in the last comment, the fade shows fine.

Comment: That works @JM-AGMS though ideally there'd be a check in there for if all checkout fields have been filled, if that makes sense.

Comment: You are welcome to put what ever logic you like before running the fadeIn.

Comment: @JM-AGMS You should please answer this question as this will be useful for the community, showing that there is an answer to this question. Thanks

Comment: And *why* it works-OP probably doesn't understand (and probably left out that it's an element added dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

Although your question doesn't specifically state it, I'm guessing your button is added to the page later by JS. In that case, you need to delegate your on click event with the below code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#place_order', function() {
  $(".purchase-processing").fadeIn( "slow" );}
);
```

Learn more about delated events here:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Don't use the `document` selector for this. Best is to get the closest static element.